# Find (or enable?!) php.ini on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: php, php5, configuration

Hiho!

Today I leave my comfort zone and want to edit my **php.ini** file and... guest what? It doesn't exist!

```
$ php --ini

Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

**Loaded Configuration File: (none)**!

What the hell? I never saw this.. Is threre a way to create or enable the PHP ini?

---

I compiled it myself:

```
$ php -v

PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Dec  3 2010 16:08:11) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Why didn't you use apt-get?

Comment: @Tim - Because it's not PHP 5.3.3

Comment: @TuiTalk - Seems like you forget to put in the path where doing compilation? try `php -i|grep config -i`, in CLI, `php -n --ini` will skip the loading php.ini

Comment: @ajreal - http://pastebin.com/pxh480YW

Comment: @TuiTalk - recompiled with option `./configure --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/lib` ... between, where is php.ini originally placed?

Comment: @ajreal - Recompilin..

Comment: @TuiTalk - and remember to copy any existing php.ini into /usr/local/lib , if there is none, copy the ini in the tmp folder **OR** simply just copy the ini in the tmp folder to /usr/local/lib because the default path is /usr/local/lib

Comment: @TuiTalk:  ubuntu 10.10 *does* provide [PHP 5.3.3 via apt](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/php/php5-fpm). So maybe no need to build it yourself after all.  See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you compiled PHP yourself without changing the default PHP ini path, it searches for php.ini in `/usr/local/lib/`.
So put `php.ini` in `/usr/local/lib/php.ini`.

In the PHP package, there is a php.ini-recommended which can be copied to that location (change dir to php-5.3.3):

```
sudo cp php.ini-recommended /usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question as asked.  But it should be pointed out that Ubuntu 10.10 (maverick) *does* include PHP 5.3.3 in the apt repository (it's the first release of Ubuntu to do so).  So the OP's reason for building from source in the first place may be based on inaccurate assumptions.  (see my answer below for more info).

Answer (score 5):

Use find to find the file:

```
find / -name "php.ini" 2> /dev/null
```

`2> /dev/null` just hides STDERR for you, due to permissions errors.

Comment: Only one file: /tmp/zend_debug/session8635259034721613818.tmp/php.ini

Answer (score 3):

Actually... Ubuntu 10.10 (maverick) *does* provide PHP 5.3.3 as part of the standard apt package system.  If you install the package `php-fpm` you'll even get the "new" FPM built in (which I expect is the whole reason you want 5.3.3 in the first place).

[check out packages.ubuntu.com for proof](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/php/php5-fpm)

That said -- if you built PHP yourself, and didn't specify any special options to configure, then `--prefix` defaulted to `/usr/local/`, and `--with-config-file-path` defaulted to `/usr/local/lib`.  So php will look for `/usr/local/lib/php.ini`.

You can change this by setting (for example) `--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc` as an option to `./configure`.

---

Just for completeness: on versions of Ubuntu prior to 10.10 (where php 5.3.3 is not part of the base distro), you can get binary apt-packages for php 5.3.3 via [dotdeb.org](http://www.dotdeb.org/).  The dotdeb repos work great on Ubuntu 8.04 Hardy.  On 10.04 Lucid, they still work, but you'll have to install a few other dependencies manually (which is kind of a drag).  Either way, follow the instructions on the [Dotdeb Instructions Page](http://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/).

Comment: Is there a way to uninstall my compiled PHP?

Comment: not really.  When you build and install something from source, you can use [checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) instead of plain old `make install`.  That will automatically track the source package's installation, allowing you to uninstall it (with varying degrees of completeness) via dpkg at some later point in time.  However, if you didn't use checkinstall when you installed it, then you're probably stuck going through an removing everything by hand.

Comment: you might try installing your "compiled version" again -- but this time use [checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) as described above.  *Then* try to uninstall using `dpkg -r`, as described at the checkinstall documentation.  That'll probably get you mostly there.  You'll need to manually remove any files you created manually (eg. /usr/local/lib/php.ini).

Answer (score 2):

From PHP5 the php.ini file in Ubuntu 10.10 or above is located here:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Comment: bash: cd: /etc/php5: File or directory not found

Answer (score 1):

php.ini in ubuntu is uaually saved in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and you got none because you don't have phpcli installed by using  this `sudo apt-get install php5-cli`

the out put after intalling it would be

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/curl.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/gd.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/sqlite.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/xdebug.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/zend-framework.ini
```

i  do have exactly php 5.3.3

`php -v` :

```
PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.1 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Oct 15 2010 14:17:04) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: If i try to install php5-cli package it'll install PHP5 too (not using the PHP 5.3.3 that I've compiled)

Comment: you have lost time compling it while you can download it as easy as apt-get

Comment: yup, and try `php -n --info`